# New Javascript Const keywords usage

Tags: javascript, class, constants

I am trying to learn a JavaScript code but below are the few statements. I am not able to understand.

```
const node = active[data]; // Is the code assiging a value to the node  
const subviews = view.subviews(); // What does view.subviews() means 
const view = node.instance;  // What does node.instance means
this.className = view.$className; // What does $ sign means
this._enabled = null;  // Why enabled was used since there was no object declared wit name _enabled.
```

Can someone explain why the above statement was used?

Comment: This code is probably inside a Class and `_enabled` is most likely a private property of said class. Your code is incomplete.

Comment: the code you've shown won't work as it shadows `view`.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple questions here.  Breaking them up and explaining the research you've done, such as quoting the documentation section you don't understand, would go a long way to getting answers.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Questions that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those examples are most likely used for aliasing purposes.

eg.

```
const node = active[data];
node.value = 7;
node.qty = 8;
```

would be the same as

```
active[data].value = 7;
active[data].qty = 8;
```

ps.  value & qty are just attributes I've made up,.

IOW: it saves having to type `active[data]` constantly.

Another alternative was using the `with`, but this is frowned up, and prone to errors.